# Reload iframe src when clicked on an a element

Tags: javascript, iframe

Is it possible to replace iframe src with a element href attribute when user clicks on it?

I have this code

http://jsfiddle.net/6Hv9P/1/

and I am trying to let the user to search using duckduckgo and when clicked on result it should replace iframe src with a href value.

Comment: When you click on search you will get results, now when you click on one of the results it will go to this address. Is it possible to reload iframe with this href value?

Comment: Sorry @debinek, I'm confused... when a link is clicked on the page contained within the `iframe`, it will automatically change within the `iframe` to the new URL (unless the link in question is doing something special with a `target` attribute or the like). So I cannot see *why* you need to manually do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible indeed. Here is an example for such a link:

```
<a href="http://jsfiddle.net" onclick="document.getElementById('siframe').src=this.href; return false;">click me</a>
```

This will replace the iframe source when the link is clicked.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Hv9P/2/).

To be more flexible you can have such code though that will make all the anchors behave in the same way:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var oFrame = document.getElementById('siframe');
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        var anchor = anchors[i];
        var curHref = anchor.href;
        if (curHref && curHref.length > 0) {
            anchor.onclick = function() {
                oFrame.src = curHref;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I am asking for. In result window you have duckduckgo search engine, when you search for 'linux' you get results, those are links and when you click on them you will go them. What I would like to get is when you click it replaces iframe src.

Comment: "when you click it replaces iframe src" - that's **exactly** what my code is doing. If you want something else please explain.

Comment: OK, lets try this way, http://jsfiddle.net/6Hv9P/1/ contains html and css code which displays duckduckgo search engine in iframe. When user clicks on <a> element in this iframe it goes to that address bu I would like to replace iframe src with this element href value.

Comment: OK, got it now. I fear that such thing is not possible - you have no control over what the user is doing inside iframe for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what I think you're trying to do is detect when the page is changed within the `iframe`, and get the URL of the new page from the `src` attribute of the that `iframe`.

Unfortunately I think you are out of luck, as the browser will not update the `src` attribute when the page changes.  And unless the page within the `iframe` comes from the same domain as the parent page, the browser security will stop you from discovering the `document.location.href` from the new page.

Comment: No, I would like to be able replace iframe src when someone clicks on <a> element with this <a> href value. So if iframe content contains <a href="kernel.org">kernel</a> it should replace iframe src with that value and reload it.